# GeoPandas geoSeries crs mismatch error

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I am running into a warning where in performing an intersect I am getting a CRS mismatch warning

> C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py:48:
> UserWarning: GeoSeries crs mismatch: esri:102001 and None
> warn("GeoSeries crs mismatch: {0} and {1}".format(this.crs,
> other.crs)).

It doesn't say where the issue is taking place but the warning happens right after the `print('You are here')` statement. I'm not sure why I am getting the error because I am pulling both geometries from the same geoDataFrame with a defined CRS of `esri:102001`. When I try to set the CRS directly on each poly by adding `.set_crs('esri: 102001')` to the end of the polys I get

> AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'set_crs'

```
sedf = pd.DataFrame({'mmsi':[getbwevals(id)[1],getbwevals(id)[1]], 'date_num':[0,9999999999], 'longitude':[getbwevals(id)[4],getbwevals(id)[6]], 'latitude':[getbwevals(id)[3],getbwevals(id)[5]]})
    aispts = gpd.GeoDataFrame((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(dflist, ignore_index=True)[['date_num', 'mmsi', 'longitude', 'latitude']])), geometry=geopandas.array.points_from_xy((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(dflist))).longitude, (pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(dflist))).latitude), crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
    septs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sedf, geometry=geopandas.array.points_from_xy(sedf.longitude, sedf.latitude), crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')
    poly1 = septs.geometry.buffer(mdist(septs)).iloc[0].set_crs('esri: 102001')
    poly2 = septs.geometry.buffer(mdist(septs)).iloc[1].set_crs('esri: 102001')
    print('You are here')
    bwe_area = gpd.GeoSeries(poly1.intersection(poly2))
    lverts = septs.append(aispts[(aispts.within(bwe_area))])
    print(lverts)
    aispts.to_file(str(id)+'_aispoints.shp')
    lverts.to_file(str(id)+'_sepoints.shp')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...build__Track.py", line 71, in <module>
    poly1 = septs.geometry.buffer(mdist(septs)).iloc[0].set_crs('esri:102001')
AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'set_crs'
```

How do I set the CRS before running the intersect?

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove the `.set_crs("esri: 102001")` method at the end of the `poly1` and `poly2` lines. You have already used the `to_crs()` method in the line where you use the `points_from_xy()` method so the polygons will be in that projection.

Comment: I rewrote the block so it goes step by step, with a print(var.crs) statement as I go, as soon as I create the bwe_area using bwe_area = gpd.GeoSeries(polys.iloc[0].intersection(polys.iloc[1])) the crs returns to none. When I try and make it a GeoDateFrame with geometry = 'geometry', crs = 'esri:102001' print crs still shows none.

Answer (score 0):

Shapely geometries are naive to projections/CRSs, which is why you are getting `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'set_crs'`.

Try the following (I'm making a few guesses here at what you are trying to do):

```
## 1. Construct and reproject your gdf
pts = geopandas.array.points_from_xy(sedf.longitude, sedf.latitude)
septs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sedf, geometry=pts, crs=4326).to_crs('esri:102001')

## 2. Buffer by a variable distance
import numpy as np
buff_dists = np.random.randint(10, size=septs.shape[0]) # specify what you want here for your variable buffer distance
septs['geometry'] = septs.buffer(buff_dists)

## 3. Fetch the polygons you want (now reprojected)
ix1, ix2 = 0, 1 # specify the indices you want
poly1 = septs.loc[ix1, 'geometry'] # this should be a shapely Polygon
poly2 = septs.loc[ix2, 'geometry']

## 4. Intersect geometries
intersection = poly1.intersection(poly2)
```

Comment: I added your suggestion and got the following results; using poly1 = septs.iloc[0, -1] poly2 = septs.iloc[1, -1] produced an error raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
dropping the -1 from the index it returns a crs mismatch. Using print(poly1.crs) shows that both polys have a none crs. I tried set_crs as outlined in the geopandas document only to get the error not attribute set_crs.

Comment: Edited the answer above. You need to use both a row and column index to get an object out of the GeoDataFrame. If you use one index, you'll get a Series or GeoSeries. If you know the labeled indices in your DataFrame, it's generally a good idea to use the labeled indices with .loc rather than the positional integer indices with .iloc.

Comment: Still throws too many indexers errors.